# Complex sql query with join and count

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently encountering a problem in writing my SQL query,

I have 3 tables :

- video_games

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Halo |
| 2 | Hulk |

- games_genres

| id | game_id |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | (genre id 1 to game id 1) |
| 2 | 1 | (genre id 2 to game id 1) |
| 2 | 2 | (genre id 2 to game id 2) |
| 3 | 2 | (genre id 3 to game id 2) |

- games_tags

| id | game_id |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | (tag id 2 to game id 1) |
| 2 | 2 | (tag id 2 to game id 2) |
| 1 | 2 | (tag id 1 to game id 2) |

HERE is what I'd like to have as result , looking for game with most genre IN(2,3) and most tags IN(1)

| videos_games.name | count_tags | common_tags | count_genres | common_genre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hulk | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2,3 |
| Halo | 0 | empty | 1 | 2 |

I currently have this, which is a syntax error

```
SELECT name,id, 
COUNT(distinct games_genres.id) as num_genres, COUNT(distinct
games_tags.id) as num_genres    INNER JOIN games_genres ON
(videos_games.id = games_genres.game_id) INNER JOIN games_tags ON
(videos_games.id = games_tags.game_id)
WHERE 
games_to_genres.genre_id IN(3,10)  games_tags.genre_id IN(31,7)
ORDER BY
deus_games.num_genres DESC
```

If anyone ever done that, I'll be reaaally thankfull !

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  MySQL doesn't support arrays, so that part of your question is unclear.

Comment: I edited my first post and I'm trying to find the more usable datas I have to explain my problem. I'm not using array as you can see, but more like stringified array like IN(10,3)

Comment: **Sample data and desired results would help** - please add those to the question

Comment: I added thoses to the questions :)

Comment: You are specifying the join but you miss from what table. Add the From statement before the first join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking for a `COUNT(*)` over a `GROUP BY` query.
You also need to unite a couple result tables.
Something like

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT name
FROM videos_games
INNER JOIN game_tags
ON game_tags.game_id = videos_games.id
WHERE game_tags.id IN(10, 3)
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM videos_games
INNER JOIN games_genres
ON games_genres.game_id = videos_games.id
WHERE games_genres.id IN(17, 22)) AS nameslist
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ;
```

See example here https://sqltest.net/#1191095

Edit: I see, then to keep the lists of common tags and genres separate, as well as their counts, you'll need something like this

```
SELECT name, COALESCE (count_tags, 0), common_tags,
 COALESCE (count_genres, 0), common_genres
FROM videos_games
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT game_id, COUNT(*) count_tags, GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') common_tags
 FROM game_tags
 WHERE id IN (2, 3)
 GROUP BY game_id) AS tag_tab
ON tag_tab.game_id = videos_games.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT game_id, COUNT(*) count_genres, GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') common_genres
 FROM games_genres
 WHERE id IN (1)
 GROUP BY game_id) AS genre_tab
ON genre_tab.game_id = videos_games.id
```

If you want to `ORDER BY` the sum of counts, make sure they are numbers.

Comment: Hi Ljisa ! Thank for your help ! This is not really what I need to, I tried to modified your query but with no success so I made tables in my initial post to show you what I really need as results. It look like I just need to splice your query in two, I'll give it a try

Comment: Oh my god lisja ! This is absolutely what I was looking for ! You are exceptionnal thank you !